# Is it possible for c++(98) STL set to hash an array of int and later check to see whether the array is present in the set or not

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, set

This might be easy but I didn't find a solution so far.
Here is what I want to do...

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int b[] = {1,2,3};

set<int*>S;

S.insert(a);    

if(S.count(b))
{
    cout<<"Job Done!"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The pointers will still be there, that doesn't tell you if they've been deleted in the mean time though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for c++(98) STL set to hash an array of int and later
>   check to see whether the array is present in the set or not

It is possible, as the second template parameter of std::set allows one to specify a custom comparator. However it is impossible to do this typesafe when the "Key" parameter is of type int*, as one cannot determine the size.

In c++11 they've introduced type std::array, that basically creates a type of array who's type is determined by the item type and array size. It also overrides operator < that performs a lexicographical comparison on all the items. If these aren't sufficient for your sorting requirements, you can change the comparator (I've added the code below).

If you can't use c++11, you can look at boost the libraries or look for Nicolai Josuttis implementation of [array](http://www.josuttis.com/cppcode/) which works for c++98:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>

int main() 
{
  typedef std::array<int,3> IntArray;
  typedef std::set<IntArray> IntArraySet;

  IntArray a = {1,2,3};
  IntArray b = {1,2,3};

  IntArraySet set;
  set.insert(a);
  set.insert(b);

  assert(set.size() == 1);

  IntArray c = {1,2,4};
  set.insert(c);
  assert(set.size() == 2);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` is an ordered container. once you insert `int*` to it it will hold the "address". In your example it will hold the address of the first element of the array `a`.
`S.count(b)` will return 0 since address of `b` doesn't equal to address of `a`.

The definition of `std::set` is so that the second parameter may be a method which defines "compare" operation ([link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/)):

> ```
> template <
>        class T,                        // set::key_type/value_type
>        class Compare = less<T>,        // set::key_compare/value_compare
>        class Alloc = allocator<T>      // set::allocator_type
> > set;
> ```

So if you write a function which will define '<' operation between two `int*` (lets say intStarComp(const int*, const int*)), the `std::set<int*>::find` will check if `a==b` by applying `!intStarComp(a,b) && !intStarComp(b,a)`. If it will return true than `a==b` and `S.count(b)` will return 1.

> *Compare* 
>   A binary predicate that takes two arguments of the same type as the elements and returns a bool. The expression comp(a,b), where
>   comp is an object of this type and a and b are key values, shall
>   return true if a is considered to go before b in the strict weak
>   ordering the function defines. The set object uses this expression to
>   determine both the order the elements follow in the container and
>   whether two element keys are equivalent (by comparing them
>   reflexively: they are equivalent if !comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)). No two
>   elements in a set container can be equivalent. This can be a function
>   pointer or a function object (see constructor for an example). This
>   defaults to less, which returns the same as applying the less-than
>   operator (a

Comment: Well, hard to write a compare function without knowing the actual array sizes. Probably better to use a `std::set<std::array<int,3>>` or `std::set<vector<int>>`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  You are right, using std::vector (or std:array) would be better and safer. But according to the example @Shafiq Islam wanted to use the native arrays. So if by design he knows that the array's size is always 3 (like in the example) and that only arrays are stored in the set and not every possible pointer to `int` then it is easy to define such function.